# How to use multiple JOIN FETCH in one JPQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, jpql

I have below entities:

```java
public class Category {
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
   private List<Topic> topics;
}

public class Topic {
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
   private List<Posts> posts;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "id")
   private Category parent;
}

public class Post {
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "id")
   private Topic parent;
   /* Post fields */
}
```

and I want to fetch all categories with joined `topics` and joined `posts` using JPQL query. I wrote query like below:

```
SELECT c FROM Category c
JOIN FETCH c.topics t
JOIN FETCH t.posts p WHERE
```

But I got the error

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
```

I found articles about this error, but these articles only describe situation where in one entity are two collections to join. My problem is a little different and I don't know how to solve it.

It is possible to do it in one query?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Considering we have the following entities:

[image: JPA entity domain model]

And, you want to fetch some parent `Post` entities along with all the associated `comments` and `tags` collections.

If you are using more than one `JOIN FETCH` directives:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    left join fetch p.tags
    where p.id between :minId and :maxId
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("minId", 1L)
.setParameter("maxId", 50L)
.getResultList();
```

Hibernate will throw the [`MultipleBagFetchException`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/):

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags [
  com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.fetching.Post.comments,
  com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.fetching.Post.tags
]
```

The reason why Hibernate throws this exception is that it does not allow fetching more than one bag because that would generate a Cartesian product.

### The worst "solution" others might try to sell you

Now, you will find lots of answers, blog posts, videos, or other resources telling you to use a `Set` instead of a `List` for your collections.

**That's terrible advice. Don't do that!**

Using `Sets` instead of `Lists` will make the `MultipleBagFetchException` go away, but the Cartesian Product will still be there, which is actually even worse, as you'll find out the performance issue long after you applied this "fix".

### The proper solution

You can do the following trick:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.id between :minId and :maxId
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("minId", 1L)
.setParameter("maxId", 50L)
.setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
.getResultList();

posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.tags t
    where p in :posts
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("posts", posts)
.setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
.getResultList();
```

> In the first JPQL query, `distinct` DOES NOT go to the SQL statement. That's why we set the `PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` JPA query hint to `false`.
>
> DISTINCT has two meanings in JPQL, and here, we need it to deduplicate the Java object references returned by `getResultList` on the Java side, not the SQL side.

As long as you fetch at most one collection using `JOIN FETCH`, you will be fine.

By using multiple queries, you will avoid the Cartesian Product since any other collection but the first one is fetched using a secondary query.

### Always avoid the `FetchType.EAGER` strategy

If you're using the `FetchType.EAGER` strategy at mapping time for `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` associations, then you could easily end up with a `MultipleBagFetchException`.

You are better off switching from `FetchType.EAGER` to `Fetchype.LAZY` since eager fetching is a terrible idea that can lead to critical application performance issues.

### Conclusion

Avoid `FetchType.EAGER` and don't switch from `List` to `Set` just because doing so will make Hibernate hide the `MultipleBagFetchException` under the carpet. Fetch just one collection at a time, and you'll be fine.

As long as you do it with the same number of queries as you have collections to initialize, you are fine. Just don't initialize the collections in a loop, as that will trigger [`N+1`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/) query issues, which are also bad for performance.

Comment: In end of this article you were said: "Although it’s always better to simply use indexed Lists or Sets". How to create indexed list?

Comment: This query gives me the following error, but still runs: `JOIN FETCH expressions cannot be defined with an identification variable.`

Comment: There's just one problem, your query returns a post and no category.

Comment: @VladMihalcea slightly unrelated - but what is the advantage of using `join fetch` vs `eager` when you join fetch all composite members?

Comment: Hi @Vlad. If i want to get one `post`, how can i tell hibernate to get the `post` and it's `comments` and then update the `post` by getting it's `tags`?

Comment: Why isnt the first result overridden? Answer: It is, but because of the additional in check in the 2nd query this works.

Comment: @ABC Because it's not overridden. It's merged.

Comment: still have the problem if we get only one post?

Comment: @roberttrudel Yes, of course. If you have a single `Post` that has N collections that have other M collections that you `JOIN FETCH`, you'd still get an N x M Cartesian Product.

Comment: Hello - i wanted to do the exact thing using LAZY fetching of the -toMany-side. That is, fetching one top level element (post) and get the toMany-relations (tags, comments,...) upon accessing the collection during post-processing. (Reason: fetching the whole tree yields a 3.2M rows result-set). Is there a simple full-code example available to inspect, since i fear our DOM is not properly designed?

Comment: @VladMihalcea you basically changed the question and redefined a new question and answered it.
Do you have anything to share on the exact question asked ?

Comment: @Napolean If my answer didn't address the question, then how do you explain the fact that the OP accepted it and the answer also got 95 upvotes? How is it that so many people found this answer relevant while you didn't?

Comment: While that probably works... what a disastrous code that is. ORM is supposed to hide all that complexity and be, well, ORM. There should be no issue for ORM to do the above thing and run multiple queries like that (hey the caller code never said how many queries to execute, it only declared the desired data). And here we are in 2023 still having that... Thanks god centuries had to pass, at least, to get rid of "distinct" hint.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov If you think that writing two queries instead of one is a disaster, then you are going to be very disappointed working with relational databases, no matter what data access framework you use. The alternative is either a Cartesian Product that will really show you the meaning of the word disaster or using a MULTISET offered by [Blaze Persistence](https://vladmihalcea.com/blaze-persistence-multiset/) or [jOOQ](https://vladmihalcea.com/fetch-multiple-to-many-jooq-multiset/). If you don't like any of these options, be the change you want to see in this world and make a better option.

Comment: @VladMihalcea didn't mean any complaint here and I am nobody to do that. It is just that I felt the original question should have been addressed in a little straight forward manner which would have 1). whether it is allowed or not to have multiple fetch in a JPQL query 2). If allowed does it have any associated issues with it ? 3). What are the better way to do this ? And your answer already covered the point 3. PS - I am a learner and don't have much exposure to the JPA

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example of complex join and multiple consition:

```
    String query_findByProductDepartmentHospital = "select location from ProductInstallLocation location "
            + " join location.product prod " + " join location.department dep "
            + " join location.department.hospital hos " + " where  prod.name = :product "
            + " and dep.name.name = :department " + " and hos.name = :hospital ";

    @Query(query_findByProductDepartmentHospital)
    ProductInstallLocation findByProductDepartmentHospital(@Param("product") String productName,@Param("department") String departName, @Param("hospital") String hospitalName);
```

Comment: This does not have a fetch so it will not initialized the joined collections.

Comment: This response has no bearing in this context. The error happens because of the fetch clause.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use @Query and @EntityGraph together, like it mentioned here [use @Query and @EntityGraph together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40084261/5080165)