# Hibernate Join and Restrictions on multiple tables

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have three tables to query with Hibernate or JPA...

Tables structure

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `insert_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `language` (
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`language_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `product_description` (
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `tag` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `product_language_idx` (`language_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_description` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `product_language` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`language_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Product     <OneToMany>     ProductDescription
Language    <ManyToOne>     ProductDescription
```

Assuming my entities are the following:

Product Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
@NamedQuery(name="Product.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Product p")
public class Product implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="product_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private int productId;
....
//bi-directional many-to-one association to ProductDescription
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
private List<ProductDescription> productDescriptions;
```

Language Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="language")
@NamedQuery(name="Language.findAll", query="SELECT l FROM Language l")
public class Language implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="language_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private int languageId;
...

//bi-directional many-to-one association to ProductDescription
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
//@JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private ProductDescription productDescription;
```

ProductDescription Entity (id is a composite key in class ProductDescriptionPK):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_description")
@NamedQuery(name="ProductDescription.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM ProductDescription p")
public class ProductDescription implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ProductDescriptionPK id;
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Language
@OneToMany(mappedBy="productDescription")
private List<Language> languages;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Product
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="product_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Product product;
```

So I have to execute a query as sample, using a join between product and product_description, where language is 1:

```
SELECT p.product_id, pd.description
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_description pd
USING ( product_id )
INNER JOIN language
USING ( language_id )
WHERE language_id = 1
```

Firstly I have used Hibernate with Criteria Query:

```
     Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Product.class,"p");
     criteria.createAlias("p.productDescriptions", "pd");
     criteria.createAlias("pd.languages", "l");
     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("l.languageId", new Integer(1)));
     result = criteria.list();
```

But that code retrieves this error:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Unknown column 'l2_.productDescription_language_id' in 'field list'

What's my issue? How can I perform queries like this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you try JPQL instead? I think that you can traslate easily your query. Got no time at this moment to test the rigth query in JPQL for your example but maybe this answer is useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088649/multiple-join-fetch-in-one-jpql-query

Comment: I'm agree with you can you get my an example please?

Comment: Eh, I think that there is an example following the link. You've got Product     <OneToMany>  ProductDescription <OneToMany> Language. And the mentioned link go Category  <OneToMany> Topic  <OneToMany> Post.

Comment: So for query with multiple join and on joined field criteria I have to use a createQuery?

Comment: You need to use a createQuery if you want to define your query with JPQL. Probably you can define a Criteria but with a lot more of code lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand completely your data model.
I think that the relationship between a `Language` and a `ProductDescription` should be one-to-many from the `Language` point of view but putting that aside ...

**UPDATED**:

Effectively, Hibernate do not map correctly the relationships using the annotations that you have indicated above. It's trying to map the strange ManyToOne relation in the table `language` and it can not find those fields: `productDescription_language_id` and `productDescription_product_id`.

I think that the correct mapping for your tables is:

**LANGUAGE ENTITY**

```
@Entity
public class Language {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="language_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long languageId;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="language")
    private List<ProductDescription> productDescriptions = 
         new ArrayList<ProductDescription>();

    // Other fields + getters and setters
}
```

**PRODUCT DESCRIPTION ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_description")
public class ProductDescription {

      @Embeddable
      public static class ProductDescriptionPK implements Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Column(name = "product_id")
      protected Long productId;

      @Column(name = "language_id")
      protected Long languageId;

      public ProductDescriptionPK() {
      }

      public ProductDescriptionPK(Long productId, Long languageId) {
        super();
        this.productId = productId;
        this.languageId = languageId;
     }

   }

   @EmbeddedId
   private ProductDescriptionPK id;

   private String description;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="language_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Language language;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="product_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Product product;

  // Other fields + getters and setters
}
```

Here is a working example of how you can chain joins with JPQL using the entities defined as you have declared them on your question.

```
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    // [UPDATED] QUERY
    String jpql = "SELECT p.id, pd.description FROM Product p "
                + "JOIN p.productDescriptions pd "
                + "JOIN pd.language l WHERE l.language_id = :idLanguage)";

    Query query = newEm.createQuery(jpql);
    query.setParameter("idLanguage", new Long(1));

    List<Object> resultList = query.getResultList();

    System.out.println( resultList.size() + " product(s) found:" );

    for (Object singleResult : resultList) {
         Object[] singleRow = (Object[]) singleResult;
         System.out.println(singleRow[0] + " " + singleRow[1]);
    }
```

That code generates this SQL query [UPDATED]

```
select
    product0_.product_id as col_0_0_,
    productdes1_.description as col_1_0_ 
from
    Product product0_ 
inner join
    product_description productdes1_ 
        on product0_.product_id=productdes1_.product_id 
inner join
    Language language2_ 
        on productdes1_.language_id=language2_.language_id 
where
    language2_.language_id=?
```

I have been reading some articles and books on the subject and using a left join fetch with a where clause is invalid. Quoting "Java Persistence with Hibernate" by Gavin King et al: 
"*The query `left join fetch i.bids b where b.amount` ... is invalid. You can't say, "Load the `Item` instances and initializes their bids collections, but only with `Bid` instances that have a certain amount*"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rubio, but I'm using Hibernate it doesnt't work with this error Unknown column 'languages2_.productDescription_language_id' in 'on clause'. Languages property in pd.productDescripotions is a List

Comment: @antonio I've used Hibernate too. Please, update your question above adding your table structure, the meaning of each table and the query that you have executed. I'll try to modify my answer accodingly.

Comment: @antonio I've updated my answer. Check it out, please.

Comment: How can I use EntityManager in my DAO?I've created only an sessionFactory Spring Bean so I can't instantiate EntityManager, can you explain how it works?

Comment: @antonio You can replace the EntityManager with the Session to create the query. Get the session from your factory and invoke session.createQuery. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I'm using Sping to injecting Hibernate sessionFactory in my DAO, so an exception is occurred when I use Entity Manager with PersistentContext to performing a JPQL. Can you show me or link how best configure for using both JPA and Hibernate in Spring? I'm trying but I'm unable to solve

Comment: @antonio But that's a different problem, isn´t it? I've recently used this sample application for learning purposes http://docs.spring.io/docs/petclinic.html It shows how to configure Spring+Hibernate. It injects the dependencies that you mention. You can find a newer version that uses Spring Boot here https://github.com/arnaldop/enhanced-pet-clinic . Please, mark my answer as accepted if it has been useful to resolve your previous problem on selecting data using Hibernate.