# How to fetch Parent Entity with its Child Entities and their Child Entities with one query with join fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Entity Parent has multiple one to many associations as you can see below.
Child entity has also one to many associations.

I successfully writed query which fetch Parent entity with child entities:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select p from Parent p " +
"left join fetch p.child1  " +
"left join fetch p.child2  " +
"where p.parentId = :parentId", Parent.class);
```

After this query executes, additional query are executed for every another level of child entities, so for every child of child.

**Is it possible to fetch parent entity with all child entities and child of child entities in one query?**

Object looks like:

```
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long parentId;

  \\other attributes

  @OneToMany(
   mappedBy = "parent",
   cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
   orphanRemoval = true
  )
  private Set<Child1> child1= new HashSet<>();

  @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "parent",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
  )
  private Set<Child2> child2= new HashSet<>();

  ...
  // other associations are removed because they are the same
  //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity

}

public class Child1{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long child1Id;

  \\other attributes

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Parent parent;

  @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "child1",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
  )
  private Set<ChildOfChild1> childOfChild1= new HashSet<>();

  //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity

 }

public class Child2{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long child2Id;

  \\other attributes

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Parent parent;

  @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "child2",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
  )
  private Set<ChildOfChild2> childOfChild2= new HashSet<>();

  //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity

 }
```

Comment: I already tried this, but parent entity is has 8 one to many associations, so when I implemented @EntityGraphs service stucked and it can not finish fetching..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use something like this:

```java
entityManager.createQuery("select p from Parent p " +
   "left join fetch p.child1 child1_ " +
   "left join fetch child1_.childOfChild1 " +
   "left join fetch p.child2 child2_ " +
   "left join fetch child2_.childOfChild2 " +
   "where p.parentId = :parentId", Parent.class);
```

And look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088649/multiple-join-fetch-in-one-jpql-query)