# Hibernate fetch multiple associations using join fetch

Tags: hibernate

I have a java entity `PullRequest` which has `Comments`, `Reviewers`, and `Labels` associations. **I'm using older version of hibernate 3.5.0-Final**.

I have an API `getPullRequests` which should return `List<PullRequest>`.
How can I fetch PullRequests using join fetch so that I can get Comments, Reviewers and Labels in 3 join queries instead of using N+1 queries.

I tried using distinct join fetch like `select distinct p from PullRequest join fetch p.Comments where p.id in (:prids)`

It is throwing BLOB can't be used in select distinct.

How can I fetch all associations using join fetch so that it won't trigger N+1 queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple JOIN FETCH in one JPQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088649/how-to-use-multiple-join-fetch-in-one-jpql-query)

Comment: Tried that approach, in the hibernate version I have mentioned,`QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` is not available.

Comment: `QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` is just query optimization that by the way broken in the newest hibernate version.

Comment: yeah, but without it, it will fetch duplicate PullRequest instances as it has joins if my understanding is correct.

Comment: You can still use `distinct` in jpql, and it will work as expected. The only side effect the query will not be so optimal as with the `QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` hint.

Comment: I tried that also, it is throwing BLOB can't be used on select in the hibernate version I'm using.