# Why does hibernate manage to use JOIN when searching on id but not on another field?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm currently using Spring Data with repositories to fetch my data.
When using the default :

```
myRepo.findById(id)
```

a single query using joins is generated :

```
Hibernate: select questionna0_.id as id1_6_0_, questionna0_.action as action2_6_0_, questionna0_.first_question_id as first_qu3_6_0_, answers1_.questionnaire_id as question5_0_1_, answers1_.id as id1_0_1_, answers1_.id as id1_0_2_, answers1_.order as order2_0_2_, answers1_.question_id as question3_0_2_, answers1_.value as value4_0_2_, validation2_.answer_id as answer_i2_1_3_, validation2_.id as id1_1_3_, validation2_.id as id1_1_4_, validation2_.answer_id as answer_i2_1_4_, validation2_.operator as operator3_1_4_, validation2_.value as value4_1_4_, questions3_.questionnaire_id as question7_5_5_, questions3_.id as id1_5_5_, questions3_.id as id1_5_6_, questions3_.answer_type as answer_t2_5_6_, questions3_.optional as optional3_5_6_, questions3_.question_key as question4_5_6_, questions3_.question_label as question5_5_6_, questions3_.question_type as question6_5_6_, answers4_.question_id as question3_0_7_, answers4_.id as id1_0_7_, answers4_.id as id1_0_8_, answers4_.order as order2_0_8_, answers4_.question_id as question3_0_8_, answers4_.value as value4_0_8_, branches5_.question_id as question3_2_9_, branches5_.id as id1_2_9_, branches5_.id as id1_2_10_, branches5_.question_id_target as question2_2_10_, conditions6_.branch_id as branch_i5_3_11_, conditions6_.id as id1_3_11_, conditions6_.id as id1_3_12_, conditions6_.operator as operator2_3_12_, conditions6_.question_id as question3_3_12_, conditions6_.value as value4_3_12_ from questionnaire questionna0_ left outer join answer answers1_ on questionna0_.id=answers1_.questionnaire_id left outer join answer_validation validation2_ on answers1_.id=validation2_.answer_id left outer join question questions3_ on questionna0_.id=questions3_.questionnaire_id left outer join answer answers4_ on questions3_.id=answers4_.question_id left outer join branch branches5_ on questions3_.id=branches5_.question_id left outer join branch_condition conditions6_ on branches5_.id=conditions6_.branch_id where questionna0_.id=?
```

but when using the same repository with a query on another field to do pretty much the same thing :

```
myRepo.findByAction(action)
```

I get multiple requests (n+1 problem...)

```
Hibernate: select questionna0_.id as id1_6_, questionna0_.action as action2_6_, questionna0_.first_question_id as first_qu3_6_ from questionnaire questionna0_ where questionna0_.action=?
Hibernate: select questions0_.questionnaire_id as question7_5_0_, questions0_.id as id1_5_0_, questions0_.id as id1_5_1_, questions0_.answer_type as answer_t2_5_1_, questions0_.optional as optional3_5_1_, questions0_.question_key as question4_5_1_, questions0_.question_label as question5_5_1_, questions0_.question_type as question6_5_1_ from question questions0_ where questions0_.questionnaire_id=?
Hibernate: select answers0_.question_id as question3_0_0_, answers0_.id as id1_0_0_, answers0_.id as id1_0_1_, answers0_.order as order2_0_1_, answers0_.question_id as question3_0_1_, answers0_.value as value4_0_1_ from answer answers0_ where answers0_.question_id=?
Hibernate: select validation0_.answer_id as answer_i2_1_0_, validation0_.id as id1_1_0_, validation0_.id as id1_1_1_, validation0_.answer_id as answer_i2_1_1_, validation0_.operator as operator3_1_1_, validation0_.value as value4_1_1_ from answer_validation validation0_ where validation0_.answer_id=?
Hibernate: select branches0_.question_id as question3_2_0_, branches0_.id as id1_2_0_, branches0_.id as id1_2_1_, branches0_.question_id_target as question2_2_1_ from branch branches0_ where branches0_.question_id=?
Hibernate: select conditions0_.branch_id as branch_i5_3_0_, conditions0_.id as id1_3_0_, conditions0_.id as id1_3_1_, conditions0_.operator as operator2_3_1_, conditions0_.question_id as question3_3_1_, conditions0_.value as value4_3_1_ from branch_condition conditions0_ where conditions0_.branch_id=?
Hibernate: select answers0_.question_id as question3_0_0_, answers0_.id as id1_0_0_, answers0_.id as id1_0_1_, answers0_.order as order2_0_1_, answers0_.question_id as question3_0_1_, answers0_.value as value4_0_1_ from answer answers0_ where answers0_.question_id=?
Hibernate: select validation0_.answer_id as answer_i2_1_0_, validation0_.id as id1_1_0_, validation0_.id as id1_1_1_, validation0_.answer_id as answer_i2_1_1_, validation0_.operator as operator3_1_1_, validation0_.value as value4_1_1_ from answer_validation validation0_ where validation0_.answer_id=?
Hibernate: select branches0_.question_id as question3_2_0_, branches0_.id as id1_2_0_, branches0_.id as id1_2_1_, branches0_.question_id_target as question2_2_1_ from branch branches0_ where branches0_.question_id=?
Hibernate: select answers0_.questionnaire_id as question5_0_0_, answers0_.id as id1_0_0_, answers0_.id as id1_0_1_, answers0_.order as order2_0_1_, answers0_.question_id as question3_0_1_, answers0_.value as value4_0_1_ from answer answers0_ where answers0_.questionnaire_id=?
```

Is the problem the fact that id is declared as @Id and not my action column ?

I can't seem to find documentation on the subject.

Here is my current entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questionnaire")
data class QuestionnaireEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    val id: UUID?,
    val action: String,
    val firstQuestionId: UUID?,
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionnaireId")
    val questions: Set<QuestionEntity>,
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionnaireId")
    val answers: Set<AnswerEntity>
)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
data class QuestionEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    val id: UUID?,
    val optional: Boolean,
    val questionLabel: String?,
    val questionKey: String?,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    val questionType: QuestionType,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    val answerType: AnswerType,
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionId")
    val answers: Set<AnswerEntity>,
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionId")
    val branches: Set<BranchEntity>
)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer")
@TypeDefs(
    TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
)
data class AnswerEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    val id: UUID?,
    val questionId: UUID,
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    val value: Map<String, Any>?,
    val order: Int,
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "answerId")
    val validations: Set<AnswerValidationEntity>
)
```

Comment: Please show your entity mapping

Comment: Edited question. I skipped some of the entities since I can reproduce the problem with only these 3

Answer (score 2):

The reason why these methods behave differently is because they are implemented very differently.

[`findById` is implemented using `EntityManager.find`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L308). This is possible because it is implemented once in `SimpleJpaRepository` which implements the methods of `CrudRepository`. `EntityManager.find` in turn honours your lazy/eager configuration on the entities.

That configuration is ignored when a query of some form is used, which is exactly what happens with other `findBy...` methods you add to your repository. You may annotate them with [`@EntityGraph`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/EntityGraph.html) to proved an entity graph specifying the fetch strategy you want it to use.

Here is an example how to use it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs

Answer (score 1):

Your problem related to [this part of documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-direct-vs-query):

> If you forget to `JOIN FETCH` all `EAGER` associations, Hibernate is going to issue a secondary select for each and every one of those which, in turn, can lead to N+1 query issues. For this reason, you should prefer `LAZY` associations.

and further:

> The Hibernate recommendation is to statically mark all associations lazy and to use dynamic fetching strategies for eagerness.
>
> This is unfortunately at odds with the JPA specification which defines that all one-to-one and many-to-one associations should be eagerly fetched by default.
>
> Hibernate, as a JPA provider, honors that default.

So, to avoid N+1 query problem, you should instead of:

```java
myRepo.findByAction(action)
```

use query like this:

```java
select q from QuestionnaireEntity q
join fetch q.questions
where q.action = :action
```

But please note that you can fetch at most one collection using `JOIN FETCH`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088649/how-to-use-multiple-join-fetch-in-one-jpql-query).

Comment: Look at the implementation of the `myRepo.findById(id)` method. This is not a query, under the hood it calls `entityManager.find`

Answer (score 1):

Better to use these design rules to not have such problems:

1. Don't use `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, use `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`
2. Don't fix fetching problems using `Set` in place of `List` for `one-to-many` association.
3. Don't use unidirectional associations like
   `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "questionnaireId")`,
   use bidirectional instead (with `@JoinColumn` on the `@ManyToOne` side and `mappedBy`). It is free and let you add elements and search them more effective.
4. Don't use `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, use `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

[what is @JoinColumn and how it is used in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542849/3405171)